# How to display dynamic multiline graph using chart.js in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, graph, linechart, linegraph

I want to display a **multiline** graph for plan1 and plan2 with **age on x-axis** and **totalnestegg on y-axis**.

I have 4 array objects with `age1` for `plan1`, `totalnestegg1` for `plan1`, `age2` for `plan2` and `totalnestegg2` for `plan2`.

I am able to display single plan but not mulitline.

`age1` has items like `[65,70,71,......,100]` with corresponding amounts in `totalamount1`.

`age2` has items like `[70,71,72,......,100]` with corresponding amounts in `totalamount1`.

I do know how to display labels for this kind, my current code looks like shown below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';

export default class DisplayGraph extends React.Component {

     state = {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Plan 1',
            fill: true,
            lineTension: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'gray',
            borderColor: 'gray',
            borderWidth: 0,
            data: this.props.totalNestEggForGraph1
          },
          {
            label: 'Plan 2',
            fill: true,
            lineTension: 0,
            backgroundColor: '#ccccff',
            borderColor: 'gray',
            borderWidth: 0,
            data: this.props.totalNestEggForGraph2
          }
        ]
      }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Line
          data={this.state}
          options={{
              
            title:{
              display:true,
              text:'Size of Retirement Savings',
              fontSize:20
            },
            legend:{
              display:true,
              position:'right'
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```